# Excel wont recognize date using openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.5, openpyxl

I have a piece of code that converts a unix date to standard U.S. date format. It displays properly in excel, however excel doesn't recognize it as a date.

```
if str(startdate).isdigit():
    startdate = int(startdate)
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(startdate)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    ws4.cell(row=cell.row,column=2).value = date
    ws4.cell(row=cell.row,column=2).number_format = 'MM DD YYYY'
```

Any idea how to get excel to see this as a date rather than text?

Comment: `date = int(startdate)` makes sure that your date is a number. In your second line of code you try to convert that number to string, which you then want to read as a number which, by the `Format` function, you wish to display as a string. If the Excel cell would hold the original number you could apply the format you have designed and it should display correctly.

Comment: Just stop once you've converted the timestamp and no need to call `int()` twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My mistake was assuming the line below created a date.

```
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(startdate)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

After venturing into the docs (Scary as hell for a noob. Does it get easier?) I realized `.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` created a string not a date.

I converted that string to a date using:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
```

Now excel recognizes it as a date.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.