# Trying to have Excel recognize datetime object as date format rather than custom using openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, openpyxl

I have a short program that is designed to add a name I provide in one column and then today's date in the column next to it. The part I'm stuck on is the date. Here's an example of the code I'm trying to use:

```
import openpyxl, datetime

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

today = datetime.date.today()

sheet['A1'].value = today

wb.save('dateTest.xlsx')
```

When I open this test workbook, cell A1 displays 2021-01-07, but the format listed in the ribbon is "Custom". Is it possible to have Excel recognize that format as "Date" instead?

I found a few other people who I think were running into similar issues, like here: [Excel wont recognize date using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947652/excel-wont-recognize-date-using-openpyxl)

However, I tried that, and got the same result. I think the link I shared just above was saying you have to give Excel the date as a datetime object, and then it recognizes it as a date, but my variable "today" is already a datetime object so I don't think that solves my problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that Excel does not support the ISO format but defaults to locale defaults. This makes little sense outside the Microsoft world which is why openpyxl defaults to ISO format in the hope that this causes the **least** confusion.